# Create a function to remove all white spaces in string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, function, replace, trim

I’m trying to build a function to remove white spaces from both ends of a string (including \n,\t) without using built in functions (i.e. trim(), replace(), split(), join())

Similar to the following code but without the .replace:

```
function myTrim(x)     
{
  return x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');  
} 

function myFunction()
{
  var str = myTrim("    Hello World!   \t ");
}
```

Comment: A `for` loop then? But why do you want this?

Comment: You would need to create a [tokenizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Tokenization) that loops over each character and decides what to do with that character

Comment: not sure if this counts... `(x.match(/\w+[\s]+\w+/g)[0] || '')`

Answer (score 1):

Here it is using `Regexp.exec`:

```js
var re = /^\s*(\S[\S\s.]*\S)\s*$/gm;

function trim(str) {
  var b = re.exec(str);
  return (b !== null) ? (re.exec(str),b[1]) : '';
}

console.log('['+trim("Hello World!")+']')
console.log('['+trim("     Hello World!")+']')
console.log('['+trim("Hello World!  \t   ")+']')
console.log('['+trim("     Hello World!  \t   ")+']')
```

> One thing to note is that you must re-call `re.exec` if the first result was non-null to clear the functions buffer.

Comment: I think this would still fall under using built-in functions.

Comment: I guess that could be.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid built-in functions, you will have to iterate over your string.

Here is a way to do it by iterating over the string 3 times:

1. A first time to remove the leading spaces
2. Then to remove the trailing spaces by iterating in reverse order
3. And then a last time to reverse the inverted string generated by the last step

```js
function myTrim(str) {
  const isSpace = c => c === ' ' || c === '\n' || c === '\r' || c === '\t';
  const loop = (str, fn) => { for (const c of str) fn(c) };
  const loopReverse = (str, fn) => { for (let i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) fn(str[i]) };
  
  let out = '';
  let found = false;
  loop(str, c => {
    if (!isSpace(c) || found) {
      found = true;
      out += c;
    }
  });
  
  found = false;
  let reversed = '';
  loopReverse(out, c => {
    if (!isSpace(c) || found) {
      found = true;
      reversed += c;
    }
  });
  
  out = '';
  loopReverse(reversed, c => out += c);
  return out;
} 

console.log(`[${myTrim('  \n  Hello World!   \t ')}]`);
console.log(`[${myTrim('Hello World! \n  \t ')}]`);
console.log(`[${myTrim('Hello World!')}]`);
```

Answer (score -3):

If I understood correctly. Try this.

```
x.replace(/[\n\t ]/g, "");
```

Comment: No, you didn't understand correctly. `Similar to the following code but without the .replace:`